baby Rudin 2.37
I'm having problem while studying baby Rudin by myself (sorry if my Eng is terrible, it is not my first language)

2.37 Theorem: If  is an infinite subset of a compact set , then  has a limit point in K.
Proof: If no point of  were a limit point of , then each ∈ would have a neighborhood  which contains at most one point of . It is clear that no finite subcollection of  can cover ; and the same is true of , since ⊂. This contradicts the compactness of .

I made a question about the words 'at most'(WHY did Rudin use this word...), and our professor said 'it is related with the definition of limit point'.

A point
x in
X
is a limit point or cluster point or accumulation point of the set
S if every neighbourhood of
x contains at least one point of
S different from
x itself.

I think, 'at most' and 'at least' are important points, but I can't find the specific reason. Can you help me?

Suppose $q\in K$. Since $E\subset K$, either $q\in E$ or it is not. If $q$ is not in $E$, then there exists a neighborhood of $q$ that contains no points of $E$ because we are assuming that $q$ is not a limit point of $E$. If $q\in E$, then any neighborhood of $q$ contains $q$ but, since $q$ is not a limit point of $E$, it is the only point of $E$ in the neighborhood.
Therefore, if $E$ has no limit point in $K$, then each $k\in K$ contains a neighborhood that contains at most one element of $E$.

It is just unravelling definitions.  If $q \in K$ is not a limit point of $E$, then there must be a neighborhood of $q$ that contains at most one point of $E$, namely $q$ itself.  The reason is that $q$ is a limit point of $E$ if every neighborhood of $q$ contains a point of $E$ distinct from $q$ (just in case $q \in E$).  When you write the negative of this statement, you get the "at most one."  The definition of limit point you've written down is not correct, and it's definitely not the one in Rudin.

Thank you for your hard work. But, I know what you said. The point is, "What my professor said," because I have to prepare for the presentation... I'll think about it a little bit more.

PLUS: I edited the wrong definition, thanks
